# speeding up query with sqlAlchemy and asyncio in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to python and i am trying to do a task that requires to query a mysql table of 50 millions records join with another table to match the data and finally group by to determine the count of record after group.
I have try something like multiprocessing.Pool to speed up the process but found out that its not recommended to use multiprocessing for I/O-bound task like querying so i switched to use async

Here is the code using SqlAlchemy-ORM and asyncio library for python:

```
class attendace(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attendance'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    activity_id = Column(BigInteger)
    user_login = Column(VARCHAR)
    groupid = Column(Integer)

class group(Base):
    __tablename__= 'group'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    term_id = Column(Integer)
    is_virtual = Column(SmallInteger)

async def check_attendance(session, page_size, page_number, result_queue):
    try:
        offset = page_size * (page_number - 1)
        result = await session.execute(\
            select(func.count(attendace.activity_id), attendace.user_login, group.term_id)\
            .join(group, attendace.groupid == group.id)\
            .where(group.term_id >= 24)\
            .group_by(group.term_id, attendace.user_login)
            .offset(offset).limit(page_size))
        res = result.all()
        # result_queue.put(result)
        print(f'Page {page_number} result: {res}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error {e}')
        return []

async def main():
    page_size = 50
    total_pages = 1

    result_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    engine = create_async_engine('mysql+aiomysql://root@localhost/db_test', echo=False, poolclass=QueuePool)

    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

    async with sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)() as session:
        tasks = [check_attendance(session, page_size, page_number, result_queue) for page_number in range(1, total_pages + 1)]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

for only page_size of 50, it has already taken about ~160s to display the result, which is equal to my whole raw sql (check_attendance is just a part of the query)

i want to ask for solutions for this large database query like this in python, is my current approach is suitable for the task ? what can i do to improve it ?

i also want to ask if there is a way to optimize the page_size and total_pages part for offset and limit in the query ? how can i make it to run through all the query until its done, not being limited by the total_pages that i provided ?

sorry for my bad english, thank you for checking this problem

i have try the multiprocessing.Pool and its still got the bottle-neck of the huge amount of data to query from the table

also, i tried the code that i uploaded and receive a very slow response result with larger page_size and total_pages

Comment: There are improvements to be made in Python but how long are the actual queries taking?  You might dramatically improve the time with a well placed index. Also offset used to be slow in MySQL you might try another strategy if you want all the results at the end of the job.

Comment: So maybe include time to execute first offset and then last offset queries.  So we can get an idea of how involved python is.

Comment: @IanWilson thanks for the answer, i have checked it again according to your advice and realized that it indeed not improve so much when adding limit and offset to the query, both in python and mysql command (for example, limit 5000 offset 0 return about 150s in both python code with async and mysql raw query). I want to handle it by dividing the query into smaller chunk to process, which led me to this approach. Can you suggest any strategy for this kind of problem

Comment: I don't use mysql much but I think there is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` which might help.  I think strategies for avoiding the limit/offset depend on the magnitude of the other relationships.  But are the foreign keys missing from your example because you made it for the question or do they really not exist, ie. `attendance.group_id` to `group.id`?  I think that might affect performance.

Comment: @IanWilson it actually because of the database setup, it did not use any FK but rather join table using specific column as condition. But i will take consider the EXPLAIN ANALYZE one, thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: I was messing around with this more but its hard to tell how to optimize without the quantities.  How many total `term_ids` are there?  Also how many total `group`s are there?

Comment: about 55 term, 41k group, 800k activity and about nearly 50m attendance record, sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the database schema here is a hack that might work.  I think it will still be pretty slow though.  It takes about 80 seconds on my laptop to finish.

```
import os
import asyncio
from itertools import islice
from random import choice

from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    Integer,
    String,
    BigInteger,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    func,
    select,
    insert,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine


# I don't have python 3.12.
def batched(iterable, n):
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) --> ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    it = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield batch


MAX_OVERFLOW = 20


POOL_SIZE=10


def get_engine(env):
    return create_async_engine(f"postgresql+asyncpg://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}", pool_size=POOL_SIZE, max_overflow=MAX_OVERFLOW)

Base = declarative_base()

class attendace(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'attendance'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    activity_id = Column(BigInteger)
    user_login = Column(String)
    groupid = Column(Integer)

class group(Base):
    __tablename__= 'group'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    term_id = Column(Integer)
    is_virtual = Column(Integer)


async def check_attendance(engine, partitioner, mod_number, result_queue):
    q = select(
            func.count(attendace.activity_id), attendace.user_login, group.term_id
    ).join(
        group, attendace.groupid == group.id
    ).where(
        group.term_id >= 24,
        # We can split the result sets in this way because
        # we group by term_id.
        # Ie. the sum of the parts is equal to the whole.
        group.term_id % partitioner == mod_number
    ).group_by(group.term_id, attendace.user_login)
    async with engine.connect() as conn:
        result = await conn.execute(q)
        res = result.all()
        # result_queue.put(result)
        print(f'Mod number {mod_number} results: {len(res)}')
        return res

async def main():
    # Must be a prime number, ideally that splits your result set evenly and
    # into appropriately sized chunks.
    PARTITIONER = 47

    result_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        await connection.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    async with engine.connect() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(populate)
    total_mod_numbers = list(range(PARTITIONER))
    # Split up jobs so we don't overload the connection pool.
    for index, mod_numbers in enumerate(batched(total_mod_numbers, n=MAX_OVERFLOW)):
        tasks = [check_attendance(engine, PARTITIONER, mod_number, result_queue) for mod_number in mod_numbers]
        res = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print (f'Batch index {index} results: {len(res)}')
    # Clean async engine
    await engine.dispose()


def populate(conn):
    """ Create a bunch of test data if the database is empty. """
    res = conn.scalar(select(func.count(group.__table__.c.id)))
    if res > 0:
        return
    rows = []
    term_ids = list(range(1, 200))
    group_ids = list(range(1, 1000000))
    for gid in group_ids:
        term_id = choice(term_ids)
        rows.append(dict(id=gid, term_id=term_id, is_virtual=0))
    conn.execute(insert(group.__table__), rows)
    conn.commit()


    rows = []
    user_logins = [str(login) for login in range(1000000)]
    activity_ids = list(range(1, 10000))
    for attend_id in range(1, 50000000):
        login = choice(user_logins)
        gid = choice(group_ids)
        act_id = choice(activity_ids)
        rows.append(dict(id=attend_id, user_login=login, groupid=gid, activity_id=act_id))
    conn.execute(insert(attendace.__table__), rows)
    conn.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (asyncio.run(main()))
```

Comment: OMG thanks so much, i will definitely try this way